# Hide div remove value

Tags: javascript

how to not submit value when div is hide? I'm using calendar fill.
if I show it, we can choose a date and send it to database and if hide it.
i wont send a value to database or the value is "no data".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMe (it, box) {
var vis = (box.checked) ? "block" : "none";
document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;}
</script>
```

Comment: can you please mention all code?

Comment: I want to make this <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="single_cal1" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status4" name="kembali" > 

when I click submit if div is hide, the value become "No Data"

Comment: 1. Update your question with additional code instead of in comments. 2. How is this related to PHP? What you are trying to do seem like pure JS.

Comment: So you don't want to post value when it's hidden right?

Comment: I'm sorry..

yes Bilal..

Answer (score 0):

disabled input elements are ignored by post request

```
 <input type="hidden" name="not_gonna_submit" disabled="disabled" value="invisible" />
```

add disabled attribute to input field when you hide that div.

Comment: I got Notice: Undefined index: kembali in C:\xampp\htdocs\tiket\insert.php on line 15

when I submit it..

Comment: @PutraPutra : This error shows, that you are going to right way, you need to check variable at server end by `isset` method.

Comment: Putra : No one can show it, without knowing you code , Please share your php code ? You should always provide all related code in your question.

Comment: <fieldset>
<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
<div class="col-md-3 xdisplay_inputx form-group has-feedback">
<input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="single_cal1" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status4" name="kembali" >
<span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span id="inputSuccess2Status5" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
</div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </fieldset>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function showMe (it, box) {
var vis = (box.checked) ? "block" : "none";
document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;}
</script>

this code for hide the div

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your function with this::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMe(it, box) {
        var vis = (box.checked) ? "block" : "none";
        var element = document.getElementById(it);
        element.style.display = vis;
        if (vis == 'none') {
            element.disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This will not post the data of your text box. I think this is you want.

Comment: @PutraPutra if your function works properly and in you vis variable 'none' value exist then my code will work

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="single_cal1" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status4" name="kembali" >

what should variable i put in this code?

Answer (score 0):

This's my code

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Pulang Pergi ? </label>
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
<div class="">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" id="PP"  onclick="showMe('div1', this)"/>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display:none" id="div1">
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Kembali<span class="required"></span>
</label>
<fieldset>
<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
<div class="col-md-3 xdisplay_inputx form-group has-feedback">
<input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="single_cal1" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status4" name="kembali" >
<span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true">
</span>
<span id="inputSuccess2Status5" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```